# why is this elementary linear algebra proof wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

The Question concerns "Linear Algebra [ Singh & Nair ] 2018" where this Exercise 1.9.1 (Page 47) is given :

[image: Question]

Is there any logical mistake in this proof? I tried $$x+x+y+y=2x+2y=2(x+y)=(1+1)(x+y)=x+y+x+y$$

$$\therefore x+x+y+y=x+y+x+y$$ $$  \implies -x+x+x+y+y-y=-x+x+y+x+y-y \implies x+y=y+x  $$

I can't see what is wrong with this... Is this wrong because for field of characteristic $2$, it will become $0$ and hence can't proceed with a proof or is there anything else? kindly help

Comment: (1) don't use images. (2) why do you think it's wrong? It's the exact same proof you as you have quoted. How do you think "cancelling" works? By adding the additive inverses. Of course in the absence of commutativity, you need to make sure your identity and inverse axioms specify they work on *both* sides, not just one. (3) What makes you think it's wrong for fields of characteristic $2$?

Comment: With this type of question you've got to provide more context because it's all about the details. Are you asking about the problem on p.47 of *Linear Algebra* by Nair and Singh? Have you looked at their axioms for a vector space? Hint: $(-x)+x=0$ and $0+x=x$ are not on the list.

Comment: @blargoner yes.. its the same problem... yeah I missed the part that they wanted to prove it only using the other axioms... so we can't do cancelling... but if a reader knows about additive inverses and the other properties require to build cancellation, then commutativity can be proved... isn't it?

Comment: @blargoner   but wait $(-x)+x=0$ is an axiom in the definition of vector spaces in the mentioned book... and $0+x=x$ is proved after that using the same axiom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to make the Definition for Vector Spaces , in various text books by various Authors & ETC.

The Question concerns "Linear Algebra [ Singh & Nair ] 2018" & hence , to make sense of the given Exercise 1.9.1 (Page 47) , we have to use the Axioms given there.

The Issue lies with Axiom 3 (Page 2)
"There exists an element in $V$ , called a zero vector , denoted by $0$ , such that $\forall x \in V , x+0=x$"
& with Axiom 4 (Page 3)
"For each $x \in V$ , there exists an element in $V$ , denoted by $−x$ , and called an additive inverse of $x$ , such that $x+(−x)=0$"

Compare that with "Terence Tao" with this article :
[https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/121.1.00s/vector_axioms.html](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/resource/general/121.1.00s/vector_axioms.html)
"there are a number of ways to phrase these axioms, and different books will do this differently, but they are all equivalent"
"$0+x = x+0 = x$"
"$(-x) + x = x + (-x) = 0$"

So , what is the Issue ?
(A) While Tao assumes (axiomatically) that $0$ commutates with very other element , Singh+Nair do not.
(B) While Tao assumes (axiomatically) that every element commutates with inverse element , Singh+Nair do not.

Proof uses $0+P=P$ , which is not yet known , we know $P+0=P$.
Proof uses $[-x]+x=0$ , which is not yet known , we know $x+[-x]=0$.

When we overcome that Issue , Proof will be right.
Currently , it is incomplete.

**PUTTING IT IN OTHER WORDS :**

(A) We can not cancel $x$ from left , since it will use $[-x]+x=0$ which is unknown at the moment.
(B) Even with that , we will get "$[-x]+x+[[other-terms]]=0+[[other-terms]]$" & we can not make it "$0+[[other-terms]]=[[other-terms]]$" , since it will use $0+x=x$ which is unknown at the moment.

### POST SCRIPT :

I see that user "blargoner" has made such Observations earlier.
I took the approach to compare with well-known Authors & check what might be missing , coming to the Same Conclusion.

Comment: So Nair and Singh thought it is redundant to axiomatically define the commutativity of the inverse and identity... and hence we cannot use those properties, if we eliminate commutativity from the axioms... but by Terrence, we can prove commutativity with the help of all other axioms... isn't it... kindly reply

Comment: Correct , though various other Authors may have other ways. The Proof given by Singh+Nair wrongly uses unknown Axioms , hence it is wrong , @PraveenKumaranP , though the Exact Same Proof is not wrong when using Axioms by Tao.